# How to construct the dynamic mongo query in golang

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm going to filter the employee records based on user condition(dynamic)

```
For Ex: 
[
map[condition:Admin condition_symbol:OR filter_by:Department operator_symbol:=] 
map[condition:User condition_symbol:AND filter_by:Department operator_symbol:=]
map[condition:01/01/2020 condition_symbol:"" filter_by:DOJ operator_symbol:>] 
]
```

I'm newbie to mongodb, How can I construct this one.
I tried and google it but no use.

I need mongo query

```
MySQL Example : select * from employee where department="ADMIN" OR department="USER" AND DOJ > "01/01/2020"
```

Dynamic

```
   Here I don't know the column name and conditions everything is dynamic, So
   Need to write the dynamic mongo query.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand your example. What are you actually trying to do? It's usually a good idea to show your code that does not work. If you havn't tried yet, you should do so before asking a question here.

Comment: Be specific in MongoDB or go language. and your requirement.

Comment: @Ashok, set of array (js) --> golang (my above example) --> need to construct the mongo db query.

Answer (score 0):

If I translate your SQL query to mongo, it would become:

```js
db.getCollection("employee").find({
    $or: [{ department: "ADMIN" }, { department: "USER" }]
    DOJ: { $gte: "01/01/2020" }
})
```

Then convert it into golang. the pipeline query will become:

```golang
query := bson.M{
    "$or": []bson.M{ { department: "ADMIN" }, { department: "USER" } },
    "DOJ": bson.M{ "$gte": "01/01/2020" },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your mysql query

```
SELECT * from employee 
 WHERE (department="ADMIN" OR department="USER") AND DOJ > "01/01/2020"
```

corresponding MongoDB query

```
db.getCollection('employee').find({
  $or: [
   {department: "ADMIN"},
   {department: "USER"}
  ],
 // take care for DOJ type is date or string
 'DOJ': { $gt: new Date("01/01/2020") }
})
```

please cross-check go lang syntax I didn't have frequent use of go language

```
// get employee collection instance from database
employeeCollection := client.Database("database").Collection("employee")
// create doj condition  
dojFilter:= bson.D{
  {"$gt": new Date("01/01/2020")}
}
// create query pipeline
pipeline := bson.D{
    {"DOJ", dojFilter},
    {"$or", []interface{}{
        bson.D{{"department", "ADMIN"}},
        bson.D{{"department", "USER"}},
    }},
}

data = employeeCollection.FindOne(context.TODO(), pipeline)
```